# Configure AlexaPi to use bluetooth speaker connected to my Raspberry Pi 3B+

Tags: bluetooth, pi-3b+, speakers, alexa

I am trying to clone Alexa on my RaspberryPi 3B+. Following are the links which I am following.

https://github.com/alexa-pi/AlexaPi

https://github.com/alexa-pi/AlexaPi/wiki/Installation

I have done all the setup and everything works perfect, Alexa responds well. Now I want to divert the sound to bluetooth speaker, what settings do I need to make. I have Raspberry Pi 3B+. I am able to connect to bluetooth speaker and play some audio too. But Alexa always speaks through the device connected to Aux cable and not through bluetooth speaker. Please let me know what changes need to be made.